# Assignment in condition. Is it a good practice?

Tags: php, coding-style

Consider:

```
if (a = 10)
{
   /* do something */
}
```

I am interested if it is a good thing to do or not and why as I have to face it quite often. Thank you in advance.

Please consider a more complex example. What would you prefer and why?

```
function getSomeData()
{
    return rand(0, 5);
}
```

First:

```
if ($result = getSomeData())
{
    print($result)
}
```

or Second:

```
$result = getSomeData();
if ($result)
{
    print($result);
}
```

Comment: No in general it is not good practice. And in this case, depending on the language, it would either throw an error (because `a` is not a boolean or assignment does not return a value) or it would always evaluate to true (integers other than `0` "normally" evaluate to true). In both cases, the `if` statement seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular example, the `if` is unnecessary, the return of the affectation is always 10.

The following would be more interesting:

```
if (a = b) 
{ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

In this case, I prefer surrounding it with another pair of parentheses, in order to clarify your intention to other coders:

```
if ((a = b)) 
{
    // do something
}
```

A good rule to remember is that if you have to think more than 10 seconds to understand a condition, maybe there is another way to express it.

Comment: Surrounding the condition with another pair of braces doesn't do anything. So I wouldn't say you're showing them you know what you do. If you want to say something to other coders, use comments or code that is more obviously right.

Comment: @justin Why have useless parenthesis? This does exactly the opposite, it shows to others you don't know what you are doing!

Comment: @svick They are parenthesis () not a pair of braces {}

Comment: @Fraser, yeah you're right, I'm always confused what term refers to what type of bracket.

Comment: I would certainly think more than 10 seconds why is your code using double parenthesis.

Comment: The 2nd set of parenthesis temporarily confuses me, they don't make anything clearer. I initially wonder if you missed another condition

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely terrible, in a condition you check for a condition, you do not try to do an assignment. I am not even sure if this will even work, and what the result will be of the if statement.

Either do this:

```
if ( a == 10 ){ /* do stuff */ }
```

Or do this:

```
a = 10;
if ( /* condition here */ ){ /* do stuff */ }
```

I believe you have mistaken the single = for the double ==.

Edit:

To respond to your more complex situation, you have to place boolean in an if statement (depending on the programming language this will either return an error or not). Placing anything else in an if statement that does not return a boolean value is in fact a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

There is no big magic!

Here, The value that an assignement returns is the value being assigned.

In your case, it is  `(a = 10)` => 10 => A non zero => hence "true"!

So, It's always returns true

Comment: No, it will throw an exception in Java: *Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean*